# Check to see if any file exists within a folder (VBScript)

Tags: vbscript, file-exists

How can I check if there exists a file within a folder with any name? I also want to ignore sub-folders.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Think I've got it but any contributions are also appreciated...

```
If Folder.Files.Count > 0 Then
   'Do something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've got it, pretty much it's

```
Const PATH = "C:\Path\to\folder"
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim folder: set folder = fso.getFolder(PATH)
if folder.files.Count <> 0 then
    'do something
end if
```

You might want to check the path is valid with `FolderExists()` before the `getFolder(PATH)` or catch the error if the path does not exist. The `files` collection does not include subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Filesystem Object (FSO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50.aspx). It sports methods such as [`FileExists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t.aspx) and [`FolderExists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xc78d8d.aspx).

Comment: But with those you have to check for a specified file which is not what I want to do. I wanted to check if ANY file existed. Thanks anyway.